# Long parameter list where a group of parameters can be grouped to an existing class, but these parameters are not gleaned from an object

Tags: java, design-patterns

The below code is the Long Parameter List Smell method.

```
// Long Parameter List Smell
public void paint (Graphics gr, 
                   double x, double y, double width, double height,
                   Boolean shouldValidate){.....}
```

The below code is the caller method calling the above smell.

```
// Caller
public void someMethod(......){
    double x = someMethod();
    double y = 200;
    double width = 100;
    double height = width/2;
    paint(gr, x, y, width, height, true);
}
```

We can notice that the parameters double x, double y, double width and double height sound like a **Rectangle** object. These parameter are not gleaned from an object so we cannot use Preserve Whole Object. The next option is Introduce Parameter Object. However,there is already the class Rectangle2D.Double that is the class in Java Library existing.

Should I group these parameters into the object of Rectangle2D.Double? The code that is refactored will be like the below. If it is ok to refactor this way. What can I call this type of refactoring?

```
// Long Parameter List Smell
public void paint (Graphics gr, 
                    Rectangle2D.Double rec
                    Boolean shouldValidate){.....}


// Caller
public void someMethod(......){
    double x = someMethod();
    double y = 200;
    double width = 100;
    double height = width/2;        
    paint(gr, 
          new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height), 
          true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
public void someMethod(......){
    Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(someMethod(), 200, 100, 50);
    paint(gr, rect, true);
}
```

?  Only a little different, but maybe a little more readable.

To answer your question on terminology, how about **Consolidate Parameter Object**?